# Do I need to make a servlet for each route in my website?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm a new Java EE web developer and trying to understand basic design patterns.  One question I have is when creating servlets, I specify the route that the servlet listens on via:

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

If my web app has the following routes:

- `domain/`
- `domain/login`

would I need to make a servlet for each route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@WebSevlet` annotation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) takes an array of values, so you should in your case be able to just annotate your method with multiple URL patterns and make the decision in the method;

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet", "/Servlet/login")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

As an alternative, you can set a name and use `urlPatterns`;

```
@WebServlet(name="MyServlet", urlPatterns={"/Servlet", "/Servlet/login"}) 
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```